# RTL in Markdown

Tags: markdown, right-to-left

Is there any existing addon spec for markdown that includes support for RTL languages?

What I'm hoping for is something like

```
This paragraph is left to right
<- This paragraph is right to left
```

Or something...  I can tweak my parser to handle this but I want to make sure it doesn't exist already.

Comment: You can just write in Hebrew/Arabic and in the code, insert the markdown in a div and put  style="direction: rtl"  it'll make the text rtl, and the rest of the page ltr

Comment: The syntax is: <div dir="rtl">

Comment: @Nir “insert the markdown in a div...” is not a solution within markdown.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is a JavaScript implementation of Markdown, which (according to the commit comments) adds support for RTL languages, namely Arabic, Hebrew, Syriac, Thaana. And it seems trivially easy to add more languages.

https://github.com/hasenj/showdown/

It's based on Showdown, http://attacklab.net/showdown.

It seems to automatically understand whether or not to render the text from right to left.
Consider this code snippet: (from the very first commit at GitHub)

```
var p_tag = "<p>";
var rtl_p_tag = "<p style='direction:rtl; text-align: right'>";

// Check for RTL paragraphs: paragraphs that start with a character
// from an RTL script.
// RTL scripts are: Arabic, Hebrew, Syriac, Thaana
// Unicode ranges reference: http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html
var first_char = str.charCodeAt(str.search(/\S/)); //first non-white-space char
if(first_char >= 1424 && first_char <= 1983) 
{
    p_tag = rtl_p_tag;
}

    str = _RunSpanGamut(str);
    str = str.replace(/^([ \t]*)/g, p_tag);
```

Hope this helps,
Magnus

Comment: [the link](https://github.com/hasenj/showdown/) is corrupt!

Answer (score 101):

Actually as my friend [Aevyz](https://github.com/Aevyz) reminded me, Markdown parses HTML in it.

You won't need to change your parser. The quickest path to solve that I could think of is this:

```
<div dir="rtl">

سلام دنیا

مرحبا العالم

שלום בעולם

ہیلو دنیا
</div>
```

So you need to **add literally two lines** to turn a whole document or an arbitrary section of it into RTL. It will be more compatible than an own script.

Comment: Among online editors, this https://jbt.github.io/markdown-editor/ has adopted the HTML in...

Comment: But unfortunately markdown attributes not working in HTML tags  :(

Comment: Can you elaborate? Which attributes? If you mean `dir="rtl"`, this attribute is not a "markdown attribute". It belongs to HTML anyway.

Answer (score 39):

Not exactly markdown, but this is how you can override paragraph direction in StackExchange questions and answers (this method does not work for comments):

add &#x202b; (RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING) in the beginning of a paragraph does control the direction of this paragraph (auto-reset on <br/> or empty line):

```
&#x202b;test מה זה? YES<br/>
test1 מה זה? NO
test2 מה זה? NO

&#x202b;test1 מה זה? YES
test2 מה זה? YES
```

> ‫test מה זה? YES
>   test1 מה זה? NO
>   test2 מה זה? NO
>
> ‫test1 מה זה? YES
>   test2 מה זה? YES

Comment: On Github issues using &#x202b; also provides correct results. A little trick is that I need to enclose the RTL paragraph in <p></p> or Github cannot render it.

Comment: You forgot to close the RLE with PDF (`&#x202c;`). But these days, use neither. __Use `&#x2067;` and close with `&#x2069;`__ the isolating versions of the former called RLI and PDI.

Comment: @RobertSiemer I did not forget to close RLE; the StackExchange implementation resets on new line.

Comment: @AlexCohn Would you recommend using it anyway?

Comment: @RobertSiemer The question is what you want to achieve; luckily, it's easy to preview the result and change it if it's not to your liking. I believe that for some strings, the isolating BiDi control chars are better, but not averywhere.

Answer (score 16):

I don't find anything in markdown standard for bidi texts.
I use my own editor : [rtlmd](http://rtlmd.codecast.ir/)

Comment: how should we use it with a github project?

Comment: wow Proud! I have the same question as Ali. But i'm not optimistic that github's markdown reader will adopt this.

Comment: In github, you just need add your content between:

<div dir="rtl> </div>

Comment: @DariushAbbasi Setting direction works for content but doesn't for titles.

Comment: @Alireza You should leave a blank line after opening `div` tag:
`<div dir="rtl">\n\n
# RTL Title
</div>`

Answer (score 14):

Just use `dir="auto"` like the below example and  it will work as you wanted:

```html
 <div dir="auto">
                با استفاده از attribute dir با مقدار auto در HTML می تونید به طور خودکار RTL رو هم داشته باشید.
  </div>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use:

```
<div align="right">
   این متن test است
</div>
```

or:

```
<div dir="auto" align="right">
   این متن test است
</div>
```

or (recommended):

```
<div dir="auto">
   این متن test است
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

מעניין. עכשיו אני רואה 
שבעצם יש גם לאתר הזה פה תמיכה בעברית וכתיבה מימין לשמאל.
הבעיה היא שזה כותב טוב, אבל בתרגום בתיבה למטה שמציגה כמו שזה אמור להראות
זה לא עובד טוב.

The above paragraph was written in Hebrew RTL and was displayed correctly in the input box but not in the preview one. However, there was no support for mixing - having one paragraph RTL and another one LTR. Seems someone needs to port the above Hebrew support in Markdown also for MarkdownSharp, SO's version. Shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Not markdown, but adding &#x202b; (RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING) in the beginning of a paragraph does control the direction of this paragraph (auto-reset on <br/> or empty line).

Answer (score 7):

You can simply add everything between `span` tags like below:

```html
<span dir="rtl" align="right">
      این یک test است
</span>
```

You may want to check [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Atcold/pytorch-Deep-Learning/master/docs/fa/README-FA.md) link to see an example in action.

Answer (score 2):

## Simple Solution

In Visual Studio Code, you can set the document direction by adding the following comment at the beginning of your Markdown file:

```markdown
<!-- language: rtl -->
```

**or**

also in the beginning of your Markdown file:

if all the file is `rtl`

```css
<style>
    * {
        direction: rtl;
    }
</style>
```

or any style you want

**or**

you can add separate custom css file like we are doing with Html file, like this in the beginning of your Markdown file :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
```

Comment: thanks, second option worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since the markdown accepts html, using this trick might be useful:

```markdown
<style>*{direction: rtl}</style>

متن راست به چپ rtl text

## **rtl title عنوان راست به چپ**
```

I use this in VSCode Jupyter Notebooks, and the good thing is you can still use markdown tags (which is not possible when you wrap the content in `<div dir="rtl">` or any other HTML tag).

Answer (score -1):

when I use align it looks better, but has no indents in bullets and numbering

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).