# How to write RTL direction in Markdown

Tags: markdown, right-to-left

How to write RTL direction in Markdown files?

For Example:

```
#عنوان

* عنوان یک
* عنوان دو
* عنوان سه
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RTL in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258028/rtl-in-markdown)

Comment: Have you seen <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258028/rtl-in-markdown>?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add `&#x202b;` at the end of your paragraph to override the direction to right-to-left.

**The one without `&#x202b;`:**

```
Test عنوان یک
```

**The one with `&#x202b;`:**

> ‫Test عنوان یک